# Как реализовать данный статус?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

В телеграмме в шапке есть статус подключение, если в телеграмме сбои, то там пишется «Соединение…», а если все ок, то «Обновление…»

Как данный статус реализировать на сокетах?

Comment: На сокетах где, зачем и для чего?

Comment: Ну, просто интересна реализация. На сайте

Comment: `Соединение_по_сокету_установлено ? 'обновление' : 'соединение'` Если соединение не установлено, то пытаемся его установить где в фоне в цикле...